# How to run c++ binary code from c# application

Tags: c#, c++, binary

I have a binary data from a c++ application that works. I want to run that specific binary code directly from my C# application.

I have this function that I got from internet:

```
    static void MemExe(byte[] buffer)
    {
        Assembly asm = Assembly.Load(buffer);

        if (asm.EntryPoint == null)
            throw new ApplicationException("No entry point found!");

        MethodInfo ePoint = asm.EntryPoint;
        object ins = asm.CreateInstance(ePoint.Name);
        ePoint.Invoke(ins, null);
    }
```

It it works well with C# binary code, but if I try to open a C++ binary code it crashes.

The exception right here:

> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly '5154816 bytes loaded Test, Version = 1.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = null' or one of its dependencies. It was made an attempt to load program with an incorrect format.

I guess it is something related to the header? I am no expert...

Is it possible to run c++ binary in the same way that the function **MemEx** 
runs C# binary?

Thanks.

Comment: The `assembly.Load()` method or its overloads cannot load unmanaged libraries (e.g. C/C++ dlls). You need to use C#'s _interoperability_ functionalities (e.g. `DllImportAttribtute`). Google for C/C++ interoprability/pinvoke for further information.

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991383/call-a-c-function-from-c-sharp) may help.

Comment: @f.nasim Thanks. But in that question I think the user is trying to execute a function that is inside the dll itself. I don't want that. I have a full application written in C++ that I want to run, but directly from its binary code.

Comment: @f.nasim And also, I need to decrypt the C++ application before running it.

Comment: @MichalHainc But I don't want to create any file to run it. I want to run it from the memory or inject the code in other process.

Comment: *"... in that question I think the user is trying to execute a function that is inside the dll itself. I don't want that. I have a full application written in C++ that I want to run, but directly from its binary code."* but you do want that. The name of the function you are wanting to call is named `Main()`.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I tried that but it didn't worked. I will try again and show you how I did to see if I'm doing that right.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain One question, reading the bytes from a EXE file, then rewriting them to a .dll file will create a valid dll?

Answer (score 0):

`Assembly.Load(...)` will only load .NET binaries.

If you want to have access to the API of binary other than .NET, you would want to use P/Invoke signatures.

If you want to run an executable, use `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(...)`.